# SwiftUI: How to run a Timer in background

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have built a basic timer app and I'm trying to figure out on how to run the timer in background.
I have tried the **Background Mode** from **Signing and Capabilities** and doesn't seem to work out for me.

I'm currently working on Xcode 12 beta 6.

**Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var start = false
    @State var count = 0
    
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // App content.
        }
        .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
            if start {
                if count < 15 {
                    count += 1
                } else {
                    start.toggle()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

If anyone of you have any suggestions on managing the timer in a better way, please do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Also a counter isn't a very good way of structuring an elapsed time timer, since `Timer` isn't very accurate; it can have significant jitters depending on what else your app is doing.  It is better to use `Date` objects to track start time and calculate elapsed time.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 , I'll make sure to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When user leaves the app, it is suspended. One generally doesn’t keep timers going when the user leaves the app. We don't want to kill the user’s battery to update a timer that really isn’t relevant until the user returns to the app.

This obviously means that you do not want to use the “counter” pattern. Instead, capture the the `Date` when you started the timer, and save it in case the user leaves the app:

```
func saveStartTime() {
    if let startTime = startTime {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(startTime, forKey: "startTime")
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "startTime")
    }
}
```

And, when the app starts, retrieved the saved `startTime`:

```
func fetchStartTime() -> Date? {
    UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "startTime") as? Date
}
```

And your timer should now not use a counter, but rather calculate the elapsed time between the start time and now:

```
let now = Date()
let elapsed = now.timeIntervalSince(startTime)

guard elapsed < 15 else {
    self.stop()
    return
}

self.message = String(format: "%0.1f", elapsed)
```

---

Personally, I'd abstract this timer and persistence stuff out of the `View`:

```
class Stopwatch: ObservableObject {
    /// String to show in UI
    @Published private(set) var message = "Not running"

    /// Is the timer running?
    @Published private(set) var isRunning = false

    /// Time that we're counting from
    private var startTime: Date? { didSet { saveStartTime() } }

    /// The timer
    private var timer: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        startTime = fetchStartTime()

        if startTime != nil {
            start()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Public Interface

extension Stopwatch {
    func start() {
        timer?.cancel() // cancel timer if any

        if startTime == nil {
            startTime = Date()
        }

        message = ""

        timer = Timer
            .publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                guard
                    let self = self,
                    let startTime = self.startTime
                else { return }

                let now = Date()
                let elapsed = now.timeIntervalSince(startTime)

                guard elapsed < 60 else {
                    self.stop()
                    return
                }

                self.message = String(format: "%0.1f", elapsed)
            }

        isRunning = true
    }

    func stop() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = nil
        startTime = nil
        isRunning = false
        message = "Not running"
    }
}

// MARK: - Private implementation

private extension Stopwatch {
    func saveStartTime() {
        if let startTime = startTime {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(startTime, forKey: "startTime")
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "startTime")
        }
    }

    func fetchStartTime() -> Date? {
        UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "startTime") as? Date
    }
}
```

Then the view can just use this `Stopwatch`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var stopwatch = Stopwatch()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(stopwatch.message)
            Button(stopwatch.isRunning ? "Stop" : "Start") {
                if stopwatch.isRunning {
                    stopwatch.stop()
                } else {
                    stopwatch.start()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

FWIW, `UserDefaults` probably isn't the right place to store this `startTime`. I'd probably use a plist or CoreData or whatever. But I wanted to keep the above as simple as possible to illustrate the idea of persisting the `startTime` so that when the app fires up again, you can make it look like the timer was running in the background, even though it wasn’t.

Comment: Hey @Rob , thanks for your detailed answer. Your code is informative. I'll make sure to implement the timer outside the view. Of course, the ideal scenario for apps with timer, is to pause the timer when in background, for example, a quiz app. However, as I mentioned before, I was looking for a solution to run the timer in background. Just a simple timer app, similar to Apple's timer in Clock app. Your 'StopWatch' class has introduced me to approach things in a different way, thanks.

Comment: “Of course, the ideal scenario for apps with timer, is to pause the timer when in background” ... It depends entirely upon the purpose of the timer. Sure in a game you might want to pause the timer. But if writing a stopwatch/timer app, then you want to to appear to continue when you leave the app. Your question was titled “How to run a Timer in background”, so I presumed you were talking about the latter.

Comment: Hi Rob! I'll be more than happy to checkmark your answer. Your answer was very useful, no doubt. However, my initial problem still remains unsolved. Now that you have understood my original question, could you help me out with it, please.

Comment: I must not understand the question, because I thought I did answer it. Your question was “how do I make a timer run in the background”, to which the answer is “technically you shouldn’t; but this how to functionally accomplish the same thing.” Perhaps you can clarify in what way the above doesn’t achieve what you want.

Comment: Alright! When you run a timer/stopwatch from your clock app in your iPhone and exit the app, the timer/stopwatch doesn't stop. And that is what I want to achieve with my app. :) I hope I could clarify myself. Btw, I approved your question, just because it was informative. Thanks.